# Is asking about shuttle services for trail heads off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Backpackers sometimes require shuttle services to get to trail heads. Sometimes the same services can also be used for slack packing.

Are these type of questions welcome on TGO.

Below is a list of example questions:

- [Devils path shuttle](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4585/devils-path-shuttle)

Comment: I had such a question *Getting to Aktse, Sweden* but it appears to have been deleted.

Comment: Hopefully we can reach a consensus, conclude and update the FAQ.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of such a thing as shuttle to trailheads... Carry on!

Comment: It is fairly common on the Appalachian Trial. How do you get to Mount Katahdin or how do you get to Springer mountain? There are several junctions with known shuttle services. They often offer slack pack services which people hiking the trail may want to know about.

Comment: @studiohack Should we update the the FAQ and vote to reopen the questions? Everybody seems to agree with the only answer. Or should we wait more time to have more people weight in their opinions?

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion, *such questions should be welcome on both The Great Outdoors and Travel*.

A shuttle service to get to or from a trail head is *uniquely* related to outdoors.  Yes, it's travel; but travel specific to outdoors is quite different from all the other travel questions as asked on Travel SE.  Similarly, outdoor food should be on-topic, even if it might also be on-topic on Cooking.

Comment: Also a valid concern (and solution) for traverses that don't end up where they started.